# Drush stuck in "Killed" loop

Tags: drush

I recently installed Drush 8.1.2 from the tarball distribution available on Github and `composer install`-ed it (this is after trying to use the `.phar` to very similar ends).

Oddly, whenever I try to run `drush` from my shell (with or without subcommands), I get no output for a while, then `drush` just keeps printing `Killed` over and over, every few seconds.

Running `ps aux | grep drush` reveals *dozens* of spawned `drush` processes; simply sending an interrupt via `^C` doesn't make the `Killed` stop. Because the processes spawn about as quickly as I can `kill` them, don't respond to `killall`, and cause surprisingly large amounts of when inputting commands, I have to reboot the system to kill the processes.

The same thing happens with the `.phar` version. This is not an issue with `drush` available via `apt`, but that's drush 5, which is horribly outdated. The same thing happens with `drush-8.1.1`, the previous release. This also occurs when installing globally via:

```
$ composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

According to my host's monitoring tools, this also sends my CPU usage skyrocketing up to about 70% until reboot, as well.

I'm on an otherwise brand-new Ubuntu 16.04 VM, with Drupal 8 installed.

**Update:** I've now tried [the snippet at `drush.org`](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) (below) on my laptop (running OS X 10.11, 8GB RAM) as well as on a much larger cloud instance with similar CPU and RAM specs, running Ubuntu. The out-of-memory error persists on this new box, but the installation succeeds without issues and produces a working `drush` on my laptop.

```
# Download latest stable release using the code below or browse to github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.
php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
# Or use our upcoming release: php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush-unstable.phar');" > drush

# Test your install.
php drush core-status

# Make `drush` executable as a command from anywhere. Destination can be anywhere on $PATH.
chmod +x drush
sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin

# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
```

I suspect that `drush` requiring more than 8GB of RAM for normal operation isn't expected behaviour; it's probably pointless to spawn boxes with higher-performance CPU and RAM configurations at this point.

**Notes**:

- I've allowed PHP to allocate 384M of RAM in my `php.ini` -- the process still respawns and prints `Killed`, all while making my system lag intensely.
- as much as I'd like to bring out `strace`, the lag on my system is a major impediment. Keystrokes take a second or two to register as long as the processes are spawning.
- This particular box has PHP 5.6, but the issue is also present on a box running PHP 7.0.

Comment: I bet you have a strange alias or symlink... I mean, when you execute ```drush``` in the console you are not really executing the drush executable but something else. EDIT: Seeing rémy comment it seems I lost the bet :D. You can't always win :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drush cc all 'Killed'](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111720/drush-cc-all-killed)

Comment: @sanzante `which drush` returns the `drush` file in the `~/.composer/vendor/drush` directory.

Comment: It's strange because the answer rémy points out talks about a single 'killed' output, but you have and infinte loop. You can debug it using strace.

Comment: what's the output of dmesg `dmesg | grep php`

Comment: @rémy dumped it into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/verandaguy/585a30947f687af7d244b4c92c3ce263). Looks like it's still an out of memory error, but should `drush` ever really need more than almost 400M?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution to the "`Killed`" loop issue (even after scaling up to the largest instance offered by my host, which has 64GB of RAM), but I've managed to get `drush` itself to work by pulling the `.phar` from Github and making it executable.

Using the install script still doesn't work (still leads to the `Killed` loop) despite making sure that everything that should be executable is executable, and installing from the tarballs or via composer likewise fails in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened for me, PHP 7.1 / Drupal 8.5

The issue itself was from an old version of drush 9 (9 beta 8 in my case)

Updating to 9.2.1 fixed it.